# Django PermissionError, during upload file

Tags: django, wsgi

I have a model:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    favicon = models.ImageField(upload_to="providers/", null=True, blank=True)
```

And in settings:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../media")
```

And in apache config I have:

```
#rest of code...
Alias /media/ /home/sever/ap/media/
<Directory /home/server/ap/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But when I 'm trying add record to this model by admin pag, when I add an images I get the error:

```
PermissionError at /admin/ap/provider/add/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/server/ap/media/providers/Samsung.png'
```

Comment: did you add `chown -R www-data:www-data` on your media folder ?

Answer (score 2):

As sebb said. I forgot add: chown -R www-data:www-data on my media folder. Now it works. Thanks!